# how to reset python font to default

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to know how to reset font back to default in code.
I used

```
Frame4.option_add("*Font", "Arial, 14")
```

to make the message frame visually bigger, now I would like to return it to normal after closing the frame.
I tried

```
window.option_add("*Font", "Courier New, 10"
```

but it kept giving error about expecting integer but got New

Comment: Try it with just `"Courier, 10"`? `"Courier"` appears to be a guaranteed supported font that actually maps to some appropriate system monospace font (often Courier New).

Comment: Yes, that seem to do it. Why is the default listed as Courier New, 10 ????? And will this work with things like "Times New Roman"???

Comment: I've definitely seen a few examples that use just `"Times"` to get Times New Roman. It's nuts, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do:

`window.option_add("*Font", "Courier, 10")`